# RIDE Robot framework Select from dynamic list

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to choose an element("Classic") from a dynamic dropdown list. Problem is that word Classic contains 2 elements.

Html page is:

```
<ul id="dynamic-14" class="results" role="list">
<li class="results-dept result">
    <div dynamic-102" class="results" role="option">
        <span class="match"/>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="results-dept result">
    <div dynamic-12" class="results" role="option">
        <span class="match"/>
            Classic
    </div>
</li>
<li class="results-dept result">
    <div dynamic-1022" class="results" role="option">
        <span class="match"/>
            Classic numbers
    </div>
</li>
```

I tried to do it with xpath using: 
//ul[@class="results"] //div[contains(.,'Classic')] 
but it gives me back 2 values so robot framework can't choose one I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user `normalize-space()` function to get rid of the leading and trailing whitespace.

```
//ul[@class="results"] //div[ normalize-space(.)='Classic']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. I used //ul[@class="results"] //div[ normalize-space()='Classic']

Comment: 宏杰李, Can I contact you somehow? I have few questions

Comment: @iljuwka  you can ask here

Comment: 2) Can I somehow make list with the code above? For example I have 3 options, I put them into own list and select the second one

Comment: @iljuwka sorry, I can not help you with that, I am only familiar with XPath